# What is "skin" time for bathroom sealant?

Tags: bathroom, sealing

I need to replace the bathroom sealant around our bath, as our bath has moved by about a cm over the years and the watertight seal has broken.

The sealant I have says "Skins in 15 minutes, dries in 24 hours".

What does "Skins" mean? I'm assuming that means that the surface goes solid (kinda like touch-dry for paint), but what's the implication of this?

What I'm trying to figure out is - when can I use the bath again? After 15 minutes, or after 24 hours (our shower is above the bath, so 24 hours is a loooong time to wait before using the shower).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 15 minutes, you can no longer work with the sealant, e.g. smoothing out any imperfections with a wet finger.  After 24 hours or so, you can use the shower again.